# How to run local c++ unit tests using google test in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, googletest

I am new to google test and xcode. Please provide any help.

I download the google test, and I use xcode to open the googletest.xcodeproj in googletest. I build the project successfully.

I want to test against my project. I have some unit tests written in myProject/test/unittest.cc The unit tests contain functions that test against myproject/src/some.cc

I did some search, I do not have `shell tool` as an option in my xcode version. 
How should I set up the project in xcode? When I try New project, and import the myProject, it opened a new window with the myProject, but when I try to add the target dependencies, I could not see gtest.framework.

May I get information on how to set up the google test for the myProject in xCode please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Xcode version 6.3 (6D570).

I used this guide http://bitrage.de/wp/google-test-with-xcode-6-and-c11/ and it worked fine for me.

I had a couple of issues:

1. I did not get a nice "archive" icon for the compiled gtest.framework as in the guide (step 7). My icon looked like a blank page.
2. I tried to unit test the code declared in a header file but implemented in a cpp file. To do that I had to:

   - remove the main() method from the cpp file being unit tested, and
   - add the cpp file in question to the "Tests" target (see step 10  in the guide) "Build Phases"->"Compile Sources".

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! What I did to make it work temporarily is: build the files through command line to generate an executable, and then in xcode, add a schema, then edit the schema, Under RUN, INFO, I cd to the generated excutable to fill Executable. Then Close and run. I will try your instructions.  Thanks so much.